# Why does "Element type is invalid: expected a string" in this simple example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was in the process of doing a Sandbox for another question but have encountered this issue which is driving me nuts. It's a simple example but I can't understand why it won't render and I get

[image]

I have a case where I want to switch between two views which in my real code are two complex components.

[image: Edit simplified-dashboard]

## App.js

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import DisplayComponent1 from "./DisplayComponent1";
import DisplayComponent2 from "./DisplayComponent2";
import Button from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const numbersToDisplay = [1, 2, 3];

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const component1 = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <DisplayComponent1
        style={{ border: "1px solid blue" }}
        numbers={numbersToDisplay}
      />
    );
  }, [numbersToDisplay]);

  const component2 = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <DisplayComponent2
        style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}
        numbers={numbersToDisplay}
      />
    );
  }, [numbersToDisplay]);
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////

  const [currentDisplayComponent, setCurrentDisplayComponent] = useState(
    component1
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        onClick={() => setCurrentDisplayComponent(component1)}
      >
        Show Display 1
      </Button>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        onClick={() => setCurrentDisplayComponent(component2)}
      >
        Show Display 2
      </Button>
      {currentDisplayComponent}
    </div>
  );
}
```

## DisplayComponent1.js & DisplayComponent2.js

```
import React from "react";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core";

export default function DisplayComponent1(props) {
  return (
    <Paper>
      <p>This is DisplayComponent1</p>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core";

export default function DisplayComponent2(props) {
  return (
    <Paper>
      <p>This is DisplayComponent2</p>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your imports from `material-ui` are incorrect.

You need to import `Paper` and `Button` as named imports

```
import {Paper} from "@material-ui/core"; // In DisplayComponent1 and DisplayComponent2
```

and

```
import {Button} from "@material-ui/core"; // In App.js
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/simplified-dashboard-plr6v?file=/src/DisplayComponent1.js:27-69)

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! One of those ones that just needs a second pair of eyes. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help :-)